# tomcat server installation error in eclipse?

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, eclipse-juno

I installed Tomcat Server successfully. When I check in my browser using localhost:8080 it responds with:

[image: this page]

However, when i configure tomcat on Eclipse, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

**EDIT:** installation process of tomcat6

```
cd /home/mpatil/Downloads/
tar zxvf apache-tomcat-6.0.37.tar.gz
cd apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin
./startup.sh
```

thanks in adavance

Comment: Try this.., This will help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003617/trouble-starting-tomcatv7-via-eclipse-kepler/35514997#35514997](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003617/trouble-starting-tomcatv7-via-eclipse-kepler/35514997#35514997) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed tomcat as is recommended, most likely the permissions on your tomcat directory are incorrect for what you want to do as borice mentions above. In my example below, I've got tomcat installed to /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.52.  By default, I have it running as a non privileged user.

[image: example with strict permissions]

For local development, we don't need to worry (too much) about permissions.  But with these permissions set I get error message you mention above:

[image: example error message]

If I go ahead and change the permissions so that I am the owner, or add a group for which I am member, I can create the server without issue.

[image: corrected permissions]

Now with proper permissions, I'm able to add the server.

[image: server added]

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot you can easily tell that you have a `Permission denied` problem.  Make sure that the file in question has the correct permissions before trying again.

Comment: hello see my screen shots its telling the configuration is corrupt  or in complete.it means what? my question is edit what i approach while installing tomcat6

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the configuration.  The **Permission denied** message is related to the file **/home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/conf/catalina.policy**. You should check the permissions of that file. You can try:
`sudo chown -R <your_user_name> /home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37`
in case somehow your files are owned by some other user, depending on how they were extracted.