# Eclipse error: "Could not load te Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/tomcatv8.0 at localhost.config

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I jst started java servlet programming. I installed Tomcat 8.0.35 server on Ubuntu 14.04 OS. When I go to localhost:8080 address it displays standard tomcat welcome page. I also installed Eclipse Java EE IDE. But when I tried to to run very simple "Hello wolrd" servlet it gives me the following message: " Could not load the Tomcat server at /Servers/Tomcatv8.0.35 at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete." I have no clue what went wrong in my case. I tried couple of solutions from previous posts but it did not help. Here is the sample code of the servlet:

```
    import Javax.servlet.http.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
             protected void doGet(HttpSrvletResponse res,
                                  HttpServletRequest req)
                            throws ServletException, IOException
             {
                      res.setContenType("text/html");
                      PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
                      out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                      out.println("<head>");
                      out.println("<title> Untitled</title>");
                      out.println("<body>");
                      out.println("<h1>Hello world</h1>");
                      out.println("</body>");
                      out.println("</html>");
             }
    }
```

Comment: For anyone still with this issue, try referring to -
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962732/could-not-load-the-tomcat-server-configuration)