# Unable to define a tomcat(v9) server in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat9

[image: The error I am receiving while trying to add the server]

I'm new to eclipse and creating dynamic web applications.Whenever I have tried to add a server to run my project, I get the following error:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.

I have also tried to add a server via 'preferences' but the same error pops up and no servers are shown in the server view.

[image]
[image]

Any way I could properly add the server and run my project?

Comment: If anyone still faces the issue, try referring here -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962732/could-not-load-the-tomcat-server-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separately downloaded zip/tar from Apache rather than an installed copy of Tomcat for your Server Runtime. Your regular user likely doesn't have Full permissions over the installed version's directories.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F