# Ubuntu 16.04: Why is the directory of tomcat 8 split up? How to reference within Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, tomcat

I'm quite new to ubuntu and on my system there is a tomcat8 installation, which i didn't set up manually. The weird thing is that this installation doesn't consist out of one but instead several directories:

```
/usr/share/tomcat8
---- /bin
---- /conf (symlink)
---- /content
---- /lib
---- /log

/etc/tomcat8/
---- /Catalina
---- /conf (symlink)
---- /policy.d

/var/lib/tomcat8/
---- /conf (symlink)
---- /lib
---- /logs (symlink)
---- /webapps
---- /work (symlink)
```

I cannot really understand why anyone would install tomcat this way since it seems quite complicated and confusing to me. The reason why i'm asking this is because it causes problems when i want to use this installation of tomcat within Eclipse. It expects the `/conf` folder to be in the same directory as `/bin` and throws an error, if i want to launch tomcat8 from within eclipse:

```
The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete
```

I found solutions for earlier versions of tomcat ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962732/could-not-load-the-tomcat-server-configuration)), but the post by user Andy didn't work for me. When i try to execute sudo ln -s /etc/tomcat8/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy, it tells me that the file already exists.

Can anybody explain to me how to solve this?

Comment: That is a common install pattern in Linux/unix environments. conf is symlinked to tomcat8 where bin resides so it is seen by the system to be in the same directory as bin.

Comment: Well, ok but where is the advantage to install everything just into one single folder? And my Eclipse throws an error that it can't find the tomcat configuration files, althoug they seem to be symlinked. How can i fix this?

Comment: Installing everything in one folder has no advantages. In Linux there are different permissions on those folders which is why they are used as such. All configuration files are in /etc/ and the /lib/ dir has working libraries (dll's in Windows) and are usually owned by root. Not sure how you configured this in Eclipse but you might edit your post and add that information. You only asked why such directories are used.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27607441/3728901

Answer (score 0):

The post made by Krishnakumar Subbaiyan solved my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27607441/3728901

Thanks to user dovy for commenting.